# RICOH SP310SFN printer on Ubuntu 10

Tags: drivers, printing, ricoh

I have a RICOH SP310SFN printer and an UBUNTU 10 series Desktop PC. But this printer does not work in Ubuntu 10 series as its driver is made for Ubuntu 15 and above.

How can I get it working?

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 10.04 or 10 are EoL (End of Live), unsupported and shouldn't be used.

Please install a current version, 16.04 LTS or newer.

Comment: It's also important to note that 10.04 and 10.10 are risky, as they do not have the latest security updates.